# Cases do not return all expected result

Tags: pattern-matching

I have the following line code:

```
Cases[g[h, r, t, b, m], x_[__, y_, __] -> y, {0, -1}]
```

I am expecting the results to be `{r,t,b}` because they match the pattern, but I am only getting `{r}.`

Can anyone suggest why I am getting only `{r}?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your aim is to remove the first and last argument:

```
Cases[g[h, r, t, b, m], _[_, y__, _] :> y, {0}]
```

Don't forget to localize `y` with `:>`

```
g[h, r, t, b, m][[2 ;; -2]] /. g -> List

List @@ (g[h, r, t, b, m][[2 ;; -2]])

Delete[List @@ fun, {{1}, {-1}}]
```

Comment: +1, but I don't think `:>` is necessary?

Comment: @mfvonh It *is* necessary.  Without it, if `y` has a global value it will be used rather than the sequence matching the pattern `y__`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh oops, duh.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `Longest`:

```
Cases[g[h, r, t, b, m], x_[__, Longest@y__, __] -> y, {0}]
```

Your single underscore after y only matches 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReplaceList[g[h, r, t, b, m], _[__, y_, __] :> y]
(*{r, t, b}*)
```